# Extract maximum hourly value each day R

Tags: r, time-series, extract

I have this data.frame:

```
                 Time    a    b    c     d
1 2015-01-01 00:00:00  863 1051 1899 25385
2 2015-01-01 01:00:00  920 1009 1658 24382
3 2015-01-01 02:00:00 1164  973 1371 22734
4 2015-01-01 03:00:00 1503  949  779 21286
5 2015-01-01 04:00:00 1826  953  720 20264
6 2015-01-01 05:00:00 2109  952  743 19905
...
                    Time   a   b    c     d
8756 2015-12-31 19:00:00   0 775 4957 28812
8757 2015-12-31 20:00:00   0 783 5615 29568
8758 2015-12-31 21:00:00   0 790 4838 28653
8759 2015-12-31 22:00:00   0 766 3841 27078
8760 2015-12-31 23:00:00  72 729 2179 24565
8761 2016-01-01 00:00:00 290 710 1612 23311
```

It represents every hour of every day for a year. I would like to extract one line per day, as a function of the maximum value of d. So at the end I want to obtain a data.frame of 365x5.

I have tried all the propositions from :[Extract the maximum value within each group in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314336/extract-the-maximum-value-within-each-group-in-a-dataframe/25314565#25314565) and also:[Daily minimum values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516377/daily-minimum-values-in-r) but it still doesn't work.

May be it could come from the way I proceed to generate my time serie?

```
library(lubridate)
start <- dmy_hms("1 Jan 2015 00:00:00")
end <- dmy_hms("01 Jan 2016 00:00:00")
time <- as.data.frame(seq(start, end, by="hours"))
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are these `mydf` and `df` different objects?.  If it is a data.table,  use `setDT(mydf)[, .(d = max(d)), by = .(Day = as.Date(Time))]`

Answer (score 3):

If we are aggregating by the 'Day', convert the 'Time' column to `Date` class stripping off the `Time` attributes, grouped by those, get the `max` of 'd'.  In the OP's post, the syntax for `data.table` involves `mydf` and `df`.  Assuming these are the same, we need

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, .(d = max(d)), by = .(Day = as.Date(Time))]
```

---

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(d ~ Day, transform(mydf, Day = as.Date(Time)), FUN = max)
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>%
   group_by(Day = as.Date(Time)) %>%
   summarise(d = max(d))
```

---

NOTE: Based on the OP's comments, columns 'a' to 'd' are `factor` class.  We need to convert it to `numeric` either at the beginning or convert it during the processing stage

```
mydf$d <- as.numeric(as.character(mydf$d)))
```

For multiple columns

```
mydf[c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')] <- lapply(mydf[c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), function(x)
       as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

#### data

```
mydf <- structure(list(Time = c("2015-01-01 00:00:00", "2015-01-01      01:00:00", 
 "2015-01-01 02:00:00", "2015-01-01 03:00:00", "2015-01-01 04:00:00", 
 "2015-01-01 05:00:00"), a = c(863L, 920L, 1164L, 1503L, 1826L, 
 2109L), b = c(1051L, 1009L, 973L, 949L, 953L, 952L), c = c(1899L, 
 1658L, 1371L, 779L, 720L, 743L), d = c(25385L, 24382L, 22734L, 
 21286L, 20264L, 19905L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: for both it returns `Error in Summary.factor(c(2144L, 1669L, 947L, 392L, 164L, 95L, 111L, 185L,  : 
  ‘max’ not meaningful for factors`

Comment: @Sebastien_H returns what?

Comment: @Sebastien_H  The description in your question is `one that contains the maximum value of d of the day.`

Comment: @Sebastien_H   I assumed that you the columns 'a' to 'd' are `numeric`.  There must be some issue while creating the data.frame.  You can do one thing before doing the aggregation.  ie. `mydf[-1] <- lapply(mydf[-1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

Comment: `Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: ‘max’ not meaningful for factors.`

Answer (score 0):

'max' doesn't work with factors. Hence convert the column (in your case, its column **d**) for which you are finding the maximum into double using **as.numeric** 
Assuming your data set is in a data frame

```
mydf$d = as.numeric(mydf$d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! Finally I choose

`do.call(rbind, lapply(split(test,test$time), function(x) {return(x[which.max(x$d),])}))`

which allows me to have a 365x5 data.frame. All your propositions were right. I just needed to change my time serie like

```
time <- as.data.frame(rep(c(1:365), each = 24))
test<- cbind.data.frame(time, df, timebis)
```

which allows me to have a 365x5 data.frame. All your propositions were right. I just needed to change my time serie.